# Xcode IDE Mac - "Run Automatically" keeps running. Is that normal?

Tags: xcode, macos

In Xcode on the Mac, and when using a playground, when I toggle the "Automatically Run" selection (as opposed to "Manually Run"), the code executes correctly, but then a status bar at the top of the screen continues to read "Running [playgroundName]"

Is this normal? I'd have though it would stop running once execution is done, and wait for any changes in the code before running again.

Or is this merely the UI's way of telling me that it's primed to continue to "Automatically Run"? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or is this merely the UI's way of telling me that it's primed to continue to "Automatically Run"?

Yeah, I think it's that. Basically it's saying, "I'm live checking your code; if you change something, I will know instantly. You don't need to press any buttons to bring it to my attention."